# DateTimePicker взять нужный день для отчёта C# (Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Добрый вечер всем. Первый вопрос. Как выбрать нужный день и время чтобы показать отчёт? Я хочу при выборе дату нужно чтобы показали сумму этого дня.
Вопрос второй: Куда будет сохраниться результат запроса и как я могу взять этот результат? Спасибо заранее.

Код:

```
    private void buttonProfit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "SELECT SUM(TotalSum) FROM TotalOutcomes WHERE Date_Time BETWEEN @dateBefore AND @dateAfter";
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SQLiteCommand(query,connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateBefore",dateTimePickerBeforeTotalOutcomes.Value.ToString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateAfter",dateTimePickerAfterTotalOutcomes.Value.ToString());
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SQLiteDataReader da = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (da.Read()){/////}
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        finally { connection.Close(); }
    }
```

Добавил SQLiteDataReader da = command.ExecuteReader(); if (da.Read()){/////} в da пишет перечисление не дало результатов.

Comment: Судя по вашему коду, отчет не будет сохранятся никуда. Вы делаете запрос, но не хотите от него получать результат. Смотрите в сторону command.ExecuteReader(), он возвращает поток ответа. В нем у вас будет лежать одна запись с результатом sum(totalSum)

Comment: @pincher1519 а как мне взять тот день который записан в базе?

Comment: Вам нужно в теле select написать имя колонки с датой. Почитайте про sql язык. После выполнения запроса DataReader будет содержать результат запроса.

Comment: SELECT SUM(TotalSum), Date_Time FROM TotalOutcomes WHERE Date_Time BETWEEN @dateBefore AND @dateAfter"

И как я выше говорил, использовать reader для чтения полученных данных

Comment: Добавил  SQLiteDataReader da = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (da.Read()){/////} в da пишет перечисление не дало результатов.

Comment: Наверно я неправильно вопрос задавал. Когда я выбираю дату из datetimePicker дата выбирается но время показывает сегодняшный, а я хочу взять тот день и тот время